# How to auto reconnect during IOError in python

Tags: python

I'm doing fetch links using python. and suddenly I lost the connection and display an error as below.

```
IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 110] Connection timed out
```

how to reconnect with the same link?

for instance

```
import urllib

a = 'http://anzaholyman.files.wordpress.com/2011/12/zip-it.gif'
image = urllib.URLopener()
image.retrieve(a,'1.jpg')
```

Comment: it would help if you showed the relevant part of your code

Comment: ....i've updated, with the example above.
would you like to help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use the `try..except` syntax:

```
import urllib

a = 'http://anzaholyman.files.wordpress.com/2011/12/zip-it.gif'
image = urllib.URLopener()
while True:
    try:
        image.retrieve(a,'1.jpg')
        break
    except IOError:
        pass
```

Answer (score 1):

If there is an actual problem loading your figure, then, a simple while loop will never end and your application will seem to hang.
To prevent this, I usually use a counter:

```
tries = 5
while tries:
    try:
        image.retrieve(a,'1.jpg')
        break
    except IOError:     
        tries -= 1     #and maybe with 0.1-1 second rest here
else:
    warn_or_raise_something
```

In order to prevent trasient problems, I also use sometimes a delay (time.sleep) between succesive tries after failed calls